# Install Tensorflow 2.2 on linux

Tags: linux, tensorflow, pip

I have GNU/Linux box, I am trying to install Tensorflow 2.2. Currently I have

```
python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.12
```

and when I try to run my code it says

```
ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`
```

So when I try to install Tensorflow 2.2

```
sudo pip-3.6 install --upgrade tensorflow==2.2.0
Collecting tensorflow==2.2.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2.0 (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2.0
```

I get the above error. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Update:

```
sudo pip-3.6 --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

-Raj

Comment: What is `sudo pip-3.6 --version` ?

Comment: @phd Updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TensorFlow 2 packages require a pip version >19.0.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install

Answer (score 2):

Starting with `Tensorflow` 2.0 Google stopped providing `manylinux1` wheels and switched to `manylinux2010` which is probably not recognized by your `pip` because it's too old. Try to upgrade: `sudo pip-3.6 install -U pip`, then verify `sudo pip-3.6 --version` and retry `sudo pip-3.6 install -U tensorflow==2.2.0`